# how to create reverse ssh tunnel to docker-toolbox which binds to 0.0.0.0

Tags: ssh, docker, boot2docker, tunnel

I recently started using docker toolbox on windows and its been quite a hard experience. A lot of things are different compared to running docker on linux as here docker is actually running inside virtual machine.

one of the issues i was still not able to resolve is how to create reverse ssh tunnel to my docker-toolbox VM and bind it to 0.0.0.0 (or to docker0 interface)

i have docker toolbox 1.10.2 and am running windows 7.

motivation: I have mysql server running on my windows machine and i would like to connect to it from my docker containers.

problem: i first tried connecting directly to 192.168.99.1 (the ip of my host windows box inside my containers) ... however that doesnt work. i think the reason is that my windows box is blocking all external connections to it. i cant change windows firewall settings as those are managed by domain.

workaround: i setup ssh connection to my VM (boot2docker inside virtualbox) with putty and i try to setup reverse proxy:

- i check the "Remote ports do the same" under SSH tunnels in putty
- source port i enter 0.0.0.0:3306
- destination i enter localhost:3306
- i check "remote" radio button

i then ssh to boot2docker ... netstat -natp | grep 3306 shows me its actually bound to 127.0.0.1

- i opened /usr/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config
- i set GatewayPorts yes
- i restard sshd with /usr/local/etc/init.d/openssh restart

i get disconnected ... when i create new connection and netstat -natp | grep 3306 i see 3306 is still bound to 127.0.0.1 only

same settings in putty (and in sshd_config) work on my debian box ... but not inside boot2docker.

any idea whats wrong ? thanks a lot.